# Colocar icones em um treeview com bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Peguei um modelo de treeview com bootstrap e estou com alguns problemas, o codigo que eles disponivilizam não usou icones, vejam o modelo aqui:https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive/blob/master/temp/template.html

Html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../asstes/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../asstes/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../asstes/css/style.css" />

</head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="../asstes/js/script.js"></script>
<script language "JavaScript" src="../asstes/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script language"JavaScript" src="../asstes/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"> </script>
<script language"JavaScript" src="../asstes/js/script.js"> </script>

<body>
<h4>Diretórios de arquivos</h4>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="tree well">
<ul>
    <li>
        <span><i class="icon-folder-open"></i> Diretorio 1</span> <a href="">Arquivos        de teste</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Diretorio 2</span> <a      href=""> teste</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Diretorio 3</span> <a  href="">Teste</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Subdiretorio</span> <a href="">Arquivos temporarios</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Subdiretorio</span> <a href="">Teste</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Subdiretorio</span> <a href="">Teste</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Subdiretorio</span> <a href="">Efraim</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Subdiretorio</span> <a href="">Arquivos</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Subdiretorio</span> <a href="">Arquivos</a>
                                    </li>
                                 </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Subdiretorio</span> <a href="">Teste</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Subdiretorio</span> <a href="">Teste</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Diretorio</span> <a href="">Teste</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
$('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');
$('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
    var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
    if (children.is(":visible")) {
        children.hide('fast');
        $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
    } else {
        children.show('fast');
        $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-minus-sign').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
});
```

Css:

```
.tree {
min-height:20px;
padding:19px;
margin-bottom:20px;
background-color:#fbfbfb;
border:1px solid #999;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
border-radius:4px;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)
}
.tree li {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:10px 5px 0 5px;
position:relative
}
.tree li::before, .tree li::after {
content:'';
left:-20px;
position:absolute;
right:auto
}
.tree li::before {
border-left:1px solid #999;
bottom:50px;
height:100%;
top:0;
width:1px
}
.tree li::after {
border-top:1px solid #999;
height:20px;
top:25px;
width:25px
}
.tree li span {
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border:1px solid #999;
border-radius:5px;
display:inline-block;
padding:3px 8px;
text-decoration:none
}
.tree li.parent_li>span {
cursor:pointer
}
.tree>ul>li::before, .tree>ul>li::after {
border:0
}
.tree li:last-child::before {
height:30px
}
.tree li.parent_li>span:hover, .tree li.parent_li>span:hover+ul li span {
background:#eee;
border:1px solid #94a0b4;
color:#000
}
```

Como faço para inserir icones ao lado, igual o template original? pois assim fica feio sem os icones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que você colocou o link errado, pois está diferente do código postado.
Mas vou postar um modelo legal que ultilizo bonito e completo que voce pode usar:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Nice-Tree-View-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-3-Easy-Tree/

Esse modelo ja vem com os botões de adicionar, editar e excluir, então boa sorte!

Comment: Links podem quebrar, poste um exemplo na sua própria resposta. Isto irá lhe garantir alguns pontos a mais.

Comment: realmente postei errado o link, mas deu certo esse seu é exatamente o que eu queria! Obrigado

Comment: Quando chegar em casa, coloco um passo a passo pra montar o codigo, vlw.